# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found Error on windows 10

Tags: python, dll, pip, jupyter-notebook

```html
C:\Users\Jeff>python
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I installed python3.6.0 on windows 10 and pip. I also was able to pip install everything but when trying to test in the python interpreter it gave me this DLL error. Looking around I found a couple of things but nothing worked. Has anyone tried this before? When using jupyter notebook it gives a kernel error

I just want to be able to use tensorflow and jupyter notebook. I have been stuck on this problem for a month now and wanted to get some new directions.

Comment: Did you try ```pip install protobuf==3.6.0``` ?

Comment: @Tibbles I had protobuf == 3.10.0 and when changing it to 3.6.0 it fixed the import issue. Thank you!